# Selecting all rows if another record in another table does not exist

Tags: mysql

I have  a table like so that stores private messages between players

```
id              int(11)
userid          int(11)
type            int(1)
global          tinyint(1)
subject         varchar(55)
content         text
receiver_id     int(11)
allianceID      int(11)
create_date     datetime
read_date       datetime
```

Now when a user chooses to delete a message from their inbox, I don't actually want to delete the message from the database. I have a separate table called `messages_hidden` with the following structure

```
userid      int(11)
message_id  int(11)
```

This `messages_hidden` table stores their userid and the corresponding message that they "deleted" from their inbox so it no longer shows up.

Now here is my query that, upon login, extracts all their messages from the database to display to them (**parts of the query have been snipped due to length**).

```
SELECT 
        msg.id,msg.type, msg.subject, msg.content, DATE_FORMAT(msg.create_date, '%b %D, %Y') as create_date,
        IF(read_date > create_date, 1, 0) AS hasRead, sender.id AS sender_id, sender.username AS sender_username, receiver.id AS receiver_id, receiver.username AS receiver_username
FROM messages AS msg
    LEFT JOIN users AS sender ON msg.userid = sender.id
    LEFT JOIN users AS receiver ON msg.receiver_id = receiver.id
WHERE (msg.receiver_id = ? OR msg.userid = ? OR msg.global = 1) ORDER BY create_date DESC
```

This query currently works fine, but how do I join `messages_hidden` and only extract messages that have not been "deleted" or hidden yet by the user?

I hope I explained my problem well enough. If you are unclear about a certain part of my question, please feel free to ask. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just add a `deleted` column to the `messages` table?

Comment: @Barmar That would delete it for both the sender and receiver. Or what if the `global` field is set to 1, which is a mass message to all players by the game or admins, if one player deletes it from their inbox it will delete it for everyone else too.